# Fetch data from ID that keeps on changing at runtime having multiple <g> inside

Tags: svg, xpath, charts, css-selectors, cypress

I am looking for a solution to fetch data from a tag which is having id as a unique attr and that keeps on changing at run time

Here is the image of the tag I want to fetch the value from this keeps on changing and the tag has no other attributes to use in Cypress.

[image: Here is the image of the tag I want to fetch value from and this keeps on changing and the tag has no other attributes to use]

I tried xpaths and cy.get() but none is helping.
...
[image: code line mentioned to reach the path tag, I want to reach there via]
..

Answer (score 4):

If the element is part of a chart, there is little point in searching for the `data-unique-id` attribute, there are probably lots of the same element on the page.

One approach is to use [traversal commands](https://example.cypress.io/commands/traversal) to work down from the chart root element - can be tricky to work out, but will be reliable.

There's some example tests here [bahmutov/chart-testing-example](https://github.com/bahmutov/chart-testing-example)

Another approach is to make your data available to the test by putting it into a property of the window (called [App Actions](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/ui-to-api-to-app-actions/#app-actions)). This saves you having to "screen-scrape" the elements.

Comment: yes, it has so many similar <g> tags I want to reach to the <g> having the data via <svg>. the one having the data inside doesn't have any other attr to use in path.

Comment: "via `<svg>`" doesn't mean a lot, since all `<g>` tags are inside an `<svg>` element.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the id is consistent, you can use a regex with `cy.get()`. In this case, I'm assuming the `id` is always something like `chart_XXXX_X`.

```js
// including a g tag
cy.get(/g\[data-unique-id="chart_\d{4}_\d"\]/)
// not including a g tag
cy.get(/\[data-unique-id="chart_\d{4}_\d"\]/)
```

Comment: I used it but I'm not sure how to reach the <g> inside the SVG using regex. please elaborate.

Comment: Can you add a more complete DOM to your question? The regex pattern should still hold, we'll probably just need to grab that `svg` element first.